# Swift String to CChar

Tags: swift, string

How does one get a `char`/`CChar` in Swift? I need to call the following method:

```
- (void)registerOption:(NSString *)longOption shortcut:(char)shortOption requirement:(GBValueRequirements)requirement;
```

I can pass the ASCII form of the char, but that is annoying. Is there a simple way to get the char at a certain index in a string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you convert a String to a CString in the Swift Language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103590/how-do-you-convert-a-string-to-a-cstring-in-the-swift-language)

Comment: Not a `CString`, a `CChar`

Comment: What's the difference? a C string is a `char *`

Comment: And a `CChar` is a `char`, without the pointer. A `char` is one character (one byte), but a `char *` is an array of characters, a string (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html)

Comment: @JoshTheGeek Can you not take the `CString` (`char *`) and take the first `char` in the array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can convert a Swift string to a Cstring and then just grab the first (and only) character:

```
var charString = "a"
var ccharOptional = charString.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)?[0]  // CChar?
var cchar = (charString.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)?[0])!       // CChar
```

Comment: Thanks. It's too bad there isn't a simpler/prettier way to do that, though.

Answer (score 3):

Using Swift 3.0:

```
let cchar = "a".utf8CString[0]
```

*(not sure when this was actually introduced, tho)*

Answer (score 2):

With Swift 5, you can use one of the two following ways in order to get a collection of `CChar` from a `String` instance.

---

## #1. Using `Swift`'s `utf8CString` property

`String` has a [`utf8CString`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2430818-utf8cstring) property. `utf8CString` has the following declaration:

```
var utf8CString: ContiguousArray<CChar> { get }
```

> A contiguously stored null-terminated UTF-8 representation of the string.

The Playground sample code below shows how to use `utf8CString`:

```
let string = "Café "
let bytes = string.utf8CString
print(bytes) // prints: [67, 97, 102, -61, -87, 32, -16, -97, -111, -115, 0]
```

---

## #2. Using `StringProtocol`'s `cString(using:)` method

Foundation provides `String` a [`cString(using:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stringprotocol/2923421-cstring) method. `cString(using:)` has the following declaration:

```
func cString(using encoding: String.Encoding) -> [CChar]?
```

> Returns a representation of the string as a C string using a given encoding.

The Playground sample code below shows how to get a collection of `CChar` from an string using `cString(using:)`:

```
import Foundation

let string = "Café "
let bytes = string.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
print(bytes) // prints: Optional([67, 97, 102, -61, -87, 32, -16, -97, -111, -115, 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

In swift3 (3.0.2):
`let cchar = "abc".cString(using: .utf8)` returns array of CChar.