# Working with C strings in Swift, or: How to convert UnsafePointer<CChar> to CString

Tags: swift, cstring

While playing with Standard C Library functions in Swift, I came across problems
when passing C strings around. As a simple example (just to demonstrate the problem), the Standard C Library function

```
char * strdup(const char *s1);
```

is exposed to Swift as

```
func strdup(_: CString) -> UnsafePointer<CChar>
```

which means that the return value of `strdup()` cannot be passed to another `strdup()` call:

```
let s1 : CString = "abc"
let s2 = strdup(s1) // OK, s2 is a UnsafePointer<CChar>
let s3 = strdup(s2) // error: could not find an overload for '__conversion' that accepts the supplied arguments
```

**My question is:** How to create a Swift `CString` from a `UnsafePointer<CChar>`,
so that the C string returned by one standard library function can be passed to another function?

The only way that I could find is (using code from [How do you convert a String to a CString in the Swift Language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103590/how-do-you-convert-a-string-to-a-cstring-in-the-swift-language)):

```
let s2a = String.fromCString(s2).bridgeToObjectiveC().UTF8String
let s3 = strdup(s2a)
```

But I do not find this satisfying for two reasons:

- It is too complicated for a simple task.
- *(Main reason:)* The above conversions works only if the C string is a valid UTF-8
  string, otherwise it fails with a runtime exception. But a C string is an *arbitrary*
  sequence of characters, delimited by a NUL character.

**Remarks/Background:** Of course, high-level functions using high-level data structures like Swift `String` or Objective-C `NSString` are preferable. But there are BSD functions in the
Standard C Library which do not have an exact counterpart in the Foundation frameworks.

I came across this problem while trying to answer [Accessing temp directory in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24281362/accessing-temp-directory-in-swift).
Here, `mkdtemp()` is a BSD function for which no exact `NSFileManager` replacement exists
(as far as I know).
 `mkdtemp()` returns a `UnsafePointer<CChar>` which has to be passed to the
`NSFileManager` function `stringWithFileSystemRepresentation` which takes a `CString`
argument.

---

*Update:* As of Xcode 6 beta 6, this problem does not exist anymore because the mapping of C-Strings into Swift has been simplified. You can just write

```
let s1 = "abc"      // String
let s2 = strdup(s1) // UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>
let s3 = strdup(s2) // UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>
let s4 = String.fromCString(s3) // String
```

Comment: Thanks to the anonymous downvoter who reminded me to bring the question up-to-date :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Swift 1.1 (or perhaps earlier) has even better C string bridging:

```
let haystack = "This is a simple string"
let needle = "simple"
let result = String.fromCString(strstr(haystack, needle))
```

The `CString` type is gone completely.

Comment: Hi Nate, thanks for your reply. `st.withCString({ $0 })` is definitely more elegant than `bridgeToObjectiveC().UTF8String`. - But `String.fromCString(up)` already fails with a runtime exception if `up` is not a valid UTF-8 string, so this issue it not solved. Try `CStringFromUnsafeCChar(foo())` where `foo()` is a C function returning a C string which is not valid UTF-8. For example: `char *foo(void) { static char buf[] = { -1, 0}; return buf; }` .

Comment: Well, drat. Bug report time -- it shouldn't be a one-way conversion from `CString` to `UnsafePointer<CChar>`.

Comment: `reinterpretCast()` works perfectly, I could apply it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24290234/1187415. Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

The String struct in Swift has an init routine you can use like:

```
let myString = String(cString: myUnsafePointer)
```

see also [init(cString: UnsafePointer)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1641523-init)