# String value to UnsafePointer<UInt8> function parameter behavior

Tags: swift

I found the following code compiles and works:

```
func foo(p:UnsafePointer<UInt8>) {
    var p = p
    for p; p.memory != 0; p++ {
        print(String(format:"%2X", p.memory))
    }
}

let str:String = "今日"
foo(str)
```

This prints `E4BB8AE697A5` and that is a valid UTF8 representation of `今日`

As far as I know, this is undocumented behavior. from [the document:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_15)

> When a function is declared as taking a UnsafePointer argument, it can accept any of the following:
>
> - nil, which is passed as a null pointer
> - An UnsafePointer, UnsafeMutablePointer, or AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer value, which is converted to UnsafePointer if necessary
> - An in-out expression whose operand is an lvalue of type Type, which is passed as the address of the lvalue
> - A [Type] value, which is passed as a pointer to the start of the array, and lifetime-extended for the duration of the call

In this case, `str` is non of them.

Am I missing something?

---

**ADDED:**

And it doesn't work if the parameter type is `UnsafePointer<UInt16>`

```
func foo(p:UnsafePointer<UInt16>) {
    var p = p
    for p; p.memory != 0; p++ {
        print(String(format:"%4X", p.memory))
    }
}
let str:String = "今日"
foo(str)
//  ^ 'String' is not convertible to 'UnsafePointer<UInt16>'
```

Even though the internal `String` representation is UTF16

```
let str = "今日"
var p = UnsafePointer<UInt16>(str._core._baseAddress)
for p; p.memory != 0; p++ {
    print(String(format:"%4X", p.memory)) // prints 4ECA65E5 which is UTF16 今日
}
```

Comment: It seems to be it is the last one, no?

Comment: I think, no. `String` is not `Array<UInt8>`

Comment: I meant to say the penultimate one. It is just like a in-out variable. Maybe the wording **"which is passed"** is not clear. It could mean "this is how the function will interpret this argument" (which I think is meant) or "this is what you have to pass in", (which I think is not meant here).

Comment: it is now documented "A String value, if Type is Int8 or UInt8. The string will automatically be converted to UTF8 in a buffer, and a pointer to that buffer is passed to the function" https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_15

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is working because of one of the interoperability changes the Swift team has made since the initial launch - you're right that it looks like it hasn't made it into the documentation yet. `String` works where an `UnsafePointer<UInt8>` is required so that you can call C functions that expect a `const char *` parameter without a lot of extra work.

Look at the C function `strlen`, defined in "shims.h":

```
size_t strlen(const char *s);
```

In Swift it comes through as this:

```
func strlen(s: UnsafePointer<Int8>) -> UInt
```

Which can be called with a `String` with no additional work:

```
let str = "Hi."
strlen(str)
// 3
```

Look at the revisions on this answer to see how C-string interop has changed over time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24438698/59541

Comment: Thanks! nice. According to `swiftc -emit-sil` outputs, it actually creates temporarily `Array<UInt>` from `String.UTF8View.Generator`. It looks *not* so fast...

Comment: Huh. Well, the "I" in SIL stands for intermediate, right? Depending on how strings are actually implemented in the compiled runtime (what if they're just `char*` under the hood?), that might be a no-op.

Comment: @rintaro: As of Swift 5 the underlying character storage is (null-terminated) UTF-8. One reason for the change was to make passing Swift strings to C functions efficient.