# UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8> from String in Swift

Tags: pointers, swift, char, lapack, accelerate-framework

I'm using the `dgeev` algorithm from the LAPACK implementation in the Accelerate framework to calculate eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a matrix. Sadly the LAPACK functions are not described in the Apple Documentation with a mere link to http://netlib.org/lapack/faq.html included.

If you look it up, you will find that the first two arguments in `dgeev` are characters signifying whether to calculate eigenvectors or not. In Swift, it is asking for `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>`. When I simply use `"N"`, I get an error. The `dgeev` function and the error are described in the following screenshot[image]

What should I do to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "problem" is that the first two parameters are declared as `char *`
and not as `const char *`, even if the strings are not modified by the function:

```
int dgeev_(char *__jobvl, char *__jobvr, ...);
```

is mapped to Swift as

```
func dgeev_(__jobvl: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>, __jobvr: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>, ...) -> Int32;
```

A possible workaround is

```
let result = "N".withCString { 
    dgeev_(UnsafeMutablePointer($0), UnsafeMutablePointer($0), &N, ...)
}
```

Inside the block, `$0` is a pointer to a NUL-terminated array of `char` with the
UTF-8 representation of the string.

---

*Remark:* `dgeev_()` does not modify the strings pointed to by the first two arguments,
so it "should be" declared as

```
int dgeev_(const char *__jobvl, const char *__jobvr, ...);
```

which would be mapped to Swift as

```
func dgeev_(__jobvl: UnsafePointer<Int8>, __jobvr: UnsafePointer<Int8>, ...) -> Int32;
```

and in that case you could simply call it as

```
let result = dgeev_("N", "N", &N, ...)
```

because Swift strings are converted to `UnsafePointer<Int8>)` automatically,
as explained in [String value to UnsafePointer<UInt8> function parameter behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27063569/string-value-to-unsafepointeruint8-function-parameter-behavior).

Answer (score 3):

It is ugly, but you can use:

```
let unsafePointerOfN = ("N" as NSString).UTF8String
var unsafeMutablePointerOfN: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8> = UnsafeMutablePointer(unsafePointerOfN)
```

and use `unsafeMutablePointerOfN` as a parameter instead of "N".

Comment: There is at least a theoretical problem with this solution: The string returned by `.UTF8String` is only guaranteed to be valid as long as the `NSString` object exists, and that could be destroyed immediately because there is no reference to it after the first line. Most probably this will not happen here because the string here is a literal constant.

Answer (score 0):

With Swift **4.2** and **5** you can use this similar approach

```
let str = "string"
let unsafePointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>(mutating: (str as NSString).utf8String)
```

You can get the result from `unsafePointer`.