# Convert Swift string into CChar pointer

Tags: c, swift, pointers

In my swift app project, I have to interact with C APIs. One of the C function takes a char pointer as input, therefore I have to convert my swift string into char pointer. But I don't know how to do it properly.

Here's my sample code:

```
var user_id_ptr : UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar> = UnsafeMutablePointer.alloc(100)
var cusID = "123"  
user_id_ptr.memory = cusID.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
```

And I always got this error:
 `Cannot assign a value of type '[CChar]' to a value of type 'CChar'`

I also check the answer in: [UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8> from String in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27876179/unsafemutablepointerint8-from-string-in-swift)

Above answer is slightly different from mine.
The example above is for only one character, but I have a string. Also, I have to pass multiple arguments to the function, I can't use something like let result = "N".withCString { dgeev_(UnsafeMutablePointer($0), UnsafeMutablePointer($0), &N, ...) }. Please show me some example for how to complete this.

Comment: Depending on whether the C function takes a `char *` or a `const char *`, either http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27876179/unsafemutablepointerint8-from-string-in-swift or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27063569/string-value-to-unsafepointeruint8-function-parameter-behavior should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, but I still got some problem. The example u post is for only one character, but I have a string. Also, I have to pass multiple  arguments to the function, I can't use something like `let result = "N".withCString { 
    dgeev_(UnsafeMutablePointer($0), UnsafeMutablePointer($0), &N, ...)
}`. Please show me some example for how to complete this.

Comment: The same technique works with (multiple) strings, but I have added it as an answer for your convenience :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the C function does not mutate the strings passed as arguments,
then the parameters *should* be declared as `const char *`, 
for example

```
int func1(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```

and in that case you can simply pass Swift strings which are automatically converted (compare [String value to UnsafePointer<UInt8> function parameter behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27063569/string-value-to-unsafepointeruint8-function-parameter-behavior)):

```
let str1 = "first string argument"
let str2 = "second string argument"

let result1 = func1(str1, str2)
```

If the function parameters are declared as `char *`

```
int func2(char *s1, char *s2);
```

then you have to use `withCString()` to obtain a temporary representation
of the string as a NUL-terminated array of UTF-8 characters:

```
let str1 = "first string argument"
let str2 = "second string argument"

// Swift 2:
let result2 = str1.withCString { s1 in
    str2.withCString { s2 in
        func2(UnsafeMutablePointer(s1), UnsafeMutablePointer(s2))
    }
}

// Swift 3:
let result2 = str1.withCString { s1 in
    str2.withCString { s2 in
        func2(UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: s1), UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: s2))
    }
}
```

Note that this still assumes that the function does not mutate the
passed strings, the `UnsafeMutablePointer()` conversion is only
needed to make the compiler happy.