# UnsafeMutablePointer calling function from Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a method defined as below in `Objective-C`:

```
- (BOOL)dataHandler:(void*)buffer length:(UInt32)length
```

In ObjC we call this method as so:

```
self [self dataHandler:(void*)[myNsString UTF8String] length:[myNsString length]];
```

When I see the prototype for this for Swift it comes out like this:

```
self.dataHandler(<#buffer: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>#>, length: <#UInt32#>)
```

I'm trying it as per below and not able to make it work:

```
self.dataHandler(buffer: UnsafeMutablePointer(response!), length: count(response!))
```

I also tried:

```
 var valueToSend = UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>(Unmanaged<NSString>.passRetained(response!).toOpaque())
 self.dataHandler(buffer: valueToSend, length: count(response!))
```

Is there anything else I haven't tried? I read the below on this:

[Get the length of a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24037711/get-the-length-of-a-string)

[UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8> from String in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27876179/unsafemutablepointerint8-from-string-in-swift)

Comment: What type has `response`?

Comment: It was a `String` in Swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar as in [UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8> from String in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27876179/unsafemutablepointerint8-from-string-in-swift), you can send the response string as UTF-8 encoded bytes
to the handler method with

```
response.withCString {
    self.dataHandler(UnsafeMutablePointer($0), length: UInt32(strlen($0)))
}
```

Inside the block, `$0` is a pointer to a NUL-terminated array of `char` with the UTF-8 representation of the string.

Note also that your Objective-C code

```
[self dataHandler:(void*)[myNsString UTF8String] length:[myNsString length]]
```

has a potential problem: `length` returns the number of UTF-16 code
points in the string, not the number of UTF-8 bytes. So this
will not pass the correct number of bytes for strings with non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Can you explain to me what it does? And why does it have to be `response.withCString { }`, why can't it directly calling `dataHandler`?

Comment: @KVISH: See update. You cannot call it directly because `String` is not a C string but a struct containing pointers to a representation of the string.