# Convert String to UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8> Swift

Tags: swift, string, unsafemutablepointer

Is there a way I could convert a String to an `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>` in Swift language, avoiding data loss?

Comment: What exactly do you need the pointer to? Do you want to *modify* the string via the pointer or is it for read-only access?

Comment: please share what have you tried already

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8> from String in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27876179/unsafemutablepointerint8-from-string-in-swift).

Comment: I've managed to handle it, thank's anyway!

Answer (score 0):

```
let s = "83"
var i: UInt8 = UInt8.init(s)!
let up: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8> = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.init(&i)
```