# Setting file path in imported C function inside Swift Framework

Tags: c, swift, xcode, cocoa, language-interoperability

I am trying to use C library source files inside my Cocoa Framework which has function named

```c
void swe_set_ephe_path(char *path);
```

Which will basically be

```c
swe_set_ephe_path(”C:\\SWEPH\\EPHE”);
```

for windows.

This library contains other data files which only work after this function is set. 
When imported to Swift the function looks like this

```swift
swe_set_ephe_path(path: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8!>)
```

Since i want to bundle up all the data files in framework and use it in my application, i have done something like this

```swift
public class SwissEphemeris {
     public init() {
        let path = Bundle.main.bundlePath
        let swePath = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>(mutating: (path as NSString).utf8String)
        swe_set_ephe_path(swePath)
     }
}
```

But it seems it's not working and the functions which needs data to be searched in files are not able to operate.

[image: Here is the picture for my directory structure]

If anybody interested to look into Swiss library documentation, check here for the link,
https://www.astro.com/swisseph/swephprg.htm#_Toc505244836

Comment: @MartinR, Thanks for Bundle.main.bundlePath thing. I have looked into both of the links you have provided but still i am not able to sort out my problem. swe_set_ephe_path(path: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8!>) takes path of data files inside framework.  `let bundle = Bundle(identifier: "com.myframework.id")` is of Bundle? type and can't be passed as String. I tried to do following but didn't work
`let path = Bundle(identifier: "com.Abhi.SwissFramework")?.bundlePath` and passed **path** as above in picture but still with no luck !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems:

First, the resource files are in the “Resources” subdirectory of the framework, not in the top-level framework directory. You can obtain a path to that directory with

```
let resourcePath = Bundle(identifier: "com.Abhi.SwissFramework")!.resourcePath!
```

or with

```
let resourcePath = Bundle(for: type(of: self)).resourcePath!
```

I suggest to force-unwrap the optionals because you *know* that the bundle and the resources directory exist. A failure would indicate a build problem which should be detected early.

Second, the C function takes a `char *` argument even though it does not mutate the passed string. Here you can use the approach from [UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8> from String in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27876179/unsafemutablepointerint8-from-string-in-swift):

```
resourcePath.withCString {
    swe_set_ephe_path(UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: $0))
}
```

Even better: use the dedicated method `withUnsafeFileSystemRepresentation()` to get the file system representation of the resource path as a C string:

```
let resourceURL = Bundle(for: type(of: self)).resourceURL!
resourceURL.withUnsafeFileSystemRepresentation {
    swe_set_ephe_path(UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: $0))
}
```

Comment: It worked, Fantastic ! Martin ! . I still didn't understand how this worked. 
```
resourcePath.withCString {
    swe_set_ephe_path(UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: $0))
}
```
Could you guide me to some resources where i can grasp this concept ?

Comment: @John: I had tried to explain it in https://stackoverflow.com/a/27876849/1187415. The methods are also all documented: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1538904-withcstring, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablepointer/2431122-init