# how to overcome CString error

Tags: objective-c, swift

how to overcome this error

```
  func selectFunc(){
    var selectQuery="select * from EmployeInfo"
    var cSql:CString = selectQuery.bridgeToObjectiveC().cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    var result:CInt=0

    var stmt:COpaquePointer = nil
    result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(appDelegate.database, cSql, -1, &stmt, nil);
    if result != SQLITE_OK
```

error occurred use of undeclared CString.how to overcome this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In older Swift versions (before Xcode 6 beta 6), a Swift `String` had explicitly to be converted 
when passed to a C function taking a `const char *` argument, as in your code.

This is no longer necessary. The `CString` type and the `bridgeToObjectiveC()` method do not exist anymore.

The current Swift compiler does the conversion
automatically (compare [String value to UnsafePointer<UInt8> function parameter behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27063569/string-value-to-unsafepointeruint8-function-parameter-behavior)) and you can just write

```
let selectQuery = "select * from EmployeInfo"
var stmt : COpaquePointer = nil
let result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(appDelegate.database, selectQuery, -1, &stmt, nil)
```