# How to pass an array of Swift strings to a C function taking a char ** parameter

Tags: c, swift, language-interoperability

I'm trying to interact with an old C terminal app from Swift. I've successfully integrated the source code and bridged the headers from C to Swift. The code compiles and runs from Xcode 6.3 beta. I've renamed the terminal app's main entry point to:

```
int initialize(int argc, char **argv);
```

Nevertheless, I'm struggling to pass the arguments from Swift to this C function. My challenge is to convert the arguments in the right format. Typical input from Swift would look like:

```
let args = ["-c", "1.2.3.4", "-p", "8000"]
```

I've tried messing with "cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)" and "withUnsafePointer", but no luck so far. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: title could be "better" by mentioning that the problem is char** parameter in a C function call.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The C function

```
int initialize(int argc, char **argv);
```

is mapped to Swift as

```
func initialize(argc: Int32, argv: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>) -> Int32
```

This is a possible solution:

```
let args = ["-c", "1.2.3.4", "-p", "8000"]

// Create [UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>]:
var cargs = args.map { strdup($0) }
// Call C function:
let result = initialize(Int32(args.count), &cargs)
// Free the duplicated strings:
for ptr in cargs { free(ptr) }
```

It uses the fact that in `strdup($0)`
the Swift string `$0` is automatically converted to a C string,
as explained in [String value to UnsafePointer<UInt8> function parameter behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27063569/string-value-to-unsafepointeruint8-function-parameter-behavior).

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. For others trying to do something similar, I should add that C passes the arguments vector starting from index 1 instead of 0.  I updated my arguments to: let args = ["", "-c", "1.2.3.4", "-p", "8000"].

Comment: If I have a command line game, do you think it's possible to run it and pass arguments to it, and extract its stdout to a text area for example in swift? Or do I have to do the game from all over using its function? @Mark

Comment: @AhmedNassar: You cannot run external programs in iOS, as far as I know.

Comment: Not external, I have the C program in my project, Can I pass to it's main function the arguments?

Comment: @AhmedNassar: That should be possible with above method. You may have to rename the main function.

Comment: But I dont want to pass all my arguments at once since I'm waiting for the stdout, how could I do this? Sorry If I'm asking a lot of silly questions, Im not experienced in C.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Martin’s answer, if you find yourself doing this a lot, you could wrap the dup/free part into a function in a similar style to `String.withCString`:

```
import Darwin

func withCStrings
  <R, S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == String>
  (strings: S, @noescape body:  (UnsafeBufferPointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>) -> R) 
  -> R  {

    let cstrings = map(strings) { strdup($0) } + [nil]

    let result = cstrings.withUnsafeBufferPointer(body)

    for ptr in cstrings { free(ptr) }

    return result
}

let execvargs = ["/usr/bin/say"] + dropFirst(Process.arguments)

let execvresult = withCStrings(execvargs) {
    execv($0[0], $0.baseAddress)
}
```