# How to pass [String] array from swift to C program?

Tags: ios, c, iphone, swift, swift4

I want to pass following Swift `String` array:

```swift
let array: [String] = ["aaa","bbb","ccc"]
```

to this C function:

```c
void printStringArray(char*[] arr) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: This should be what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275377/swift-convert-a-string-array-to-a-to-a-c-string-array-pointer

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29469158/how-to-pass-an-array-of-swift-strings-to-a-c-function-taking-a-char-parameter