# Convert Swift String array to c char**

Tags: c, arrays, swift

I'm calling a C library from Swift 4 and I have troubles converting a `[String]` to `const char *[]`.

The C API defines this method:

```
int getDREFs(const char* drefs[], unsigned char count);
```

which is exposed in Swift as

```
public func getDREFs(_ drefs: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<Int8>?>!, _ count: UInt8) -> Int32
```

The Swift wrapper I'm trying to write is the following

```
public func get(drefs: [String]) throws {

    var cDrefs = [UnsafePointer<Int8>]()
    for dref in drefs {
        cDrefs.append(dref.cString(using: .utf8)!)
    }
    let pDrefs = UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<Int8>>(&cDrefs)
    getDREFFs(pDrefs, drefs.count)

}
```

but the error I get is

`Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<Int8>>' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<Int8>?>!'`

what am I missing?

Comment: Any feedback on the answer? Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: yes sorry, I forgot to accept your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getDREFSs` expects a pointer to an array of *optional* `Int8` pointers.
Also the second argument must be converted to `UInt8`.

So this would compile:

```
public func get(drefs: [String]) -> Int {
    var cDrefs = [UnsafePointer<Int8>?]()
    for dref in drefs {
        cDrefs.append(dref.cString(using: .utf8))
    }
    let result = getDREFs(&cDrefs, UInt8(drefs.count))
    return Int(result)
}
```

But a quick test shows that is does not work if called with
multiple strings. The reason is that the arrays
returned by  `dref.cString(using: .utf8)`
can already be deallocated (and the pointer invalid)
when the C function is called.

Here is a working version, a slight modification of
[Convert a Swift Array of String to a to a C string array pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275377/convert-a-swift-array-of-string-to-a-to-a-c-string-array-pointer/38275792#38275792) for
this particular case:

```
public func get(drefs: [String]) -> Int {
    var cargs = drefs.map { UnsafePointer<Int8>(strdup($0)) }
    let result = getDREFs(&cargs, UInt8(drefs.count))
    for ptr in cargs { free(UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: ptr)) }
    return Int(result)
}
```