# Passing swift string to c function char *

Tags: c, swift, language-interoperability

I am trying to pass a string argument from swift function wrapper to C function which takes char*.

This a c function

```c
long swe_fixstar2_ut(char* star, double tjd_ut, long iflag, double* xx, char* serr);
```

The parameter star must provide for at least 41 characters for the returned star name. If a star is found, its name is returned. This function searches the star name from the txt file.

When imported to Swift function looks like this

```swift
swe_fixstar_ut(star: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>!, tjd_ut: Double, iflag: int32,
                xx: UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>!, serr: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>!)
```

I want to achieve something like this

```swift
public func sweFixStarsUT(star: String, tjdUT: Double, iFlag: Int32) {
      let xx: UnsafeMutablePointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>.allocate(capacity:6)
      let serr:UnsafeMutablePointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>.allocate(capacity:256)
      swe_fixstar_ut(star, tjdUT, iFlag, xx, serr)
}
```

I looked around few of the similar questions but it doesn't solve my problem.

[Convert a Swift Array of String to a to a C string array pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275377/convert-a-swift-array-of-string-to-a-to-a-c-string-array-pointer?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[How to pass an array of Swift strings to a C function taking a char ** parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29469158/how-to-pass-an-array-of-swift-strings-to-a-c-function-taking-a-char-parameter)

Actually this function comes from Swiss ephemeris C library. Here is the link if you guys are interested to look

https://www.astro.com/swisseph/swephprg.htm#_Toc505244846

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I read the doc, the parameter `star` is used for both in and out, so your `star` of the Swift function should be `inout`.

And `long` is imported as `Int`, and in Apple's 64-bit platforms, it represents 64-bit signed integer type, if it is actually 32-bit, you may need to update the source files of your C code. I assume it as `Int`.

So, I would write the bridging code like this:

```
public func sweFixStarsUT(star: inout String, tjdUT: Double, iFlag: Int) {
    let starLen = max(star.utf8.count, 41)
    var starBuf: [CChar] = Array(repeating: 0, count: starLen+1)
    strcpy(&starBuf, star)
    var xx: [Double] = Array(repeating: 0.0, count: 6)
    var serr: [CChar] = Array(repeating: 0, count: 256)
    swe_fixstar2_ut(&starBuf, tjdUT, iFlag, &xx, &serr)
    star = String(cString: starBuf)
}
```

I prefer using Arrays when passing pointers to a C-function, when the function does not keep the pointers for later use. With using Arrays, you have no need to worry about deallocating.

You can see how the code is converting the input `star` to an Array of CChar and coverting back the Array into String.

If you find something wrong with this code, please tell me.

Comment: I knew who would answer this if I am not fast enough :)

Comment: Btw, `long` is `Int` on both 32-bit and 64-bit (Apple) platforms.

Comment: Thanks as always, @MartinR. So, the problem is that the OP is using `Int32` for the originally `long` parameter `iFlg`. The library may be written in _long is 32-bit_ environment which may cause some issues in 64-bit environment.

Comment: @OOPer What kind of issues it may bring ?

Comment: @John, when you assume `long` as `Int32` and it's working, the library may be written only for 32-bit platforms. Such libraries may not work in 64-bit environment. If the library is confirmed to work with 64-bit platforms, or your code is meant only for 32-bit platforms, that may not be a problem.

Comment: @OOPer, @OOPer,This library contains swe_set_ephe_path() function which needs to be called at first before using any other functions .I have used
`let path = Bundle.main.bundlePath
        let swePath = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>(mutating: (path as NSString).utf8String)
        swe_set_ephe_path(swePath)`
to call it inside my framework. I have included necessary txt files also  but the functions like `swe_fixstars_ut` is not able to search star name from txt file. What may i have been missing? Thanks !

Comment: I do not know anything about how to use the library, but your usage of `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.init(mutating:)` is wrong. But that's another issue (`swe_set_ephe_path` would keep the pointer given), you should better start another thread.