# Swift3: How to create a char**?

Tags: c, swift, swift3, dynamic-library

I try to call a C function from a dynamic library from Swift (3). 
I want to do mirror the function call as in the following c example.

This is the function declaration

```
extern int parseArgs(int argc, char **argv);
```

And this is the correct use of it:

```
char* args[] = {"-arg1","-arg2","-arg3"};
parseArgs (sizeof(args)/sizeof(char*), args);
```

So far, I have been able to convert Strings into the right format. This is what I am using.

```
typealias CHAR = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>
func cString(_ s: String) -> CHAR {
    return UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>(mutating: (s as NSString).utf8String!)
}
```

So far, so good. Now, how do I continue?

```
typealias CHAR_ARRAY = UnsafeMutablePointer<CHAR?>
```

This seems to be the correct type. But I cannot do the instantiation. And knowing me and my lack of low level programming: even above CHAR solution is not ideally. How would you call the `parseArgs` function?

Comment: You will want to use an UnsafeMutableBufferPointer https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/unsafemutablebufferpointer

Comment: This should be what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29469158/interact-with-legacy-c-terminal-app-from-swift.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to a similar question.