# Casting a tuple of pointers to a pointer of pointers

Tags: swift, ffmpeg, libav

I have piece of C code:

```
#define AV_NUM_DATA_POINTERS 8
uint8_t *data[AV_NUM_DATA_POINTERS];
```

In the swift generated interface this looks like:

```
var data: (UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>?, UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>?, UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>?, UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>?, UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>?, UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>?, UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>?, UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>?)
```

There's a function that needs this `data` variable. It's representation in C is as follows:

```
int sws_scale(..., const uint8_t *const srcSlice[], ...);
```

However swift produces the following signature:

```
func sws_scale(..., _ srcSlice: UnsafePointer<UnsafePointer<UInt8>?>!, ...) -> Int32
```

What's the best way to cast the huge tuple to a type that would work for the `sws_scale` function?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29469158/how-to-pass-an-array-of-swift-strings-to-a-c-function-taking-a-char-parameter

Answer (score 2):

Example from [Swift.org - UnsafeRawPointer Migration](https://swift.org/migration-guide-swift3/se-0107-migrate.html):

```
var bytes: (CChar, CChar, CChar, CChar) = (0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0)
let name: String = withUnsafePointer(to: &bytes) { ptr -> String in
   return String(cString: UnsafeRawPointer(ptr).assumingMemoryBound(to: CChar.self))
}
```

Applied to `sws_scale`:

```
var data: (UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>?, UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>?, UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>?, UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>?, UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>?, UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>?, UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>?, UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>?)
withUnsafePointer(to: data) { dataPointer in
   let dataPointer =
      UnsafeRawPointer(dataPointer)
         .assumingMemoryBound(to: UnsafePointer<UInt8>?.self)

   sws_scale(…, dataPointer, …)
}
```

---

DO NOT do the following:

```
withUnsafePointer(to: &data.0)
```

I ran into a memory alignment issue when using the above in an optimized build.