# Free C-malloc()'d memory in Swift?

Tags: c, swift, pointers, memory-management

I'm using the Swift compiler's Bridging Header feature to call a C function that allocates memory using `malloc()`. It then returns a pointer to that memory. The function prototype is something like:

```
char *the_function(const char *);
```

In Swift, I use it like this:

```
var ret = the_function(("something" as NSString).UTF8String)

let val = String.fromCString(ret)!
```

Forgive my ignorance concerning Swift but normally in C, if the_function() is malloc'ing memory and returning it, somebody else needs to free() it at some point.

Is this being handled by Swift somehow or am I leaking memory in this example?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Swift does not manage memory that is allocated with `malloc()`, you have to free the memory eventually:

```
let ret = the_function("something") // returns pointer to malloc'ed memory
let str = String.fromCString(ret)!  // creates Swift String by *copying* the data
free(ret) // releases the memory

println(str) // `str` is still valid (managed by Swift)
```

---

Note that a Swift `String` is automatically converted to a UTF-8
string when passed to a C function taking a `const char *` parameter
as described in [String value to UnsafePointer<UInt8> function parameter behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27063569/string-value-to-unsafepointeruint8-function-parameter-behavior).
That's why

```
let ret = the_function(("something" as NSString).UTF8String)
```

can be simplified to

```
let ret = the_function("something")
```

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet! While it seems simple and obvious, I had no idea on how to do it at first because I wasn't aware that Swift `String` initializer **copy** the C buffer. Even the example code in the [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/using_imported_c_functions_in_swift) forgot to call `free()`.