# How can I use `syslog` in Swift

Tags: macos, swift, syslog

Looks like `syslog()` function is not available in Swift 2.

How can I send a message to `syslog` on OS X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that

```
void syslog(int priority, const char *message, ...);
```

takes a variable argument list and is not imported to Swift. You can
use

```
void vsyslog(int priority, const char *message, va_list args);
```

instead and define a wrapper function in Swift:

```
func syslog(priority : Int32, _ message : String, _ args : CVarArgType...) {
    withVaList(args) { vsyslog(priority, message, $0) }
}

syslog(LOG_ERR, "i=%ld, x=%f", 123, 34.56)
```

Note that string arguments have to be passed as C strings:

```
syslog(LOG_ERR, "status=%s", "OK".cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))
```

---

*Alternatively,* use `NSLog()` which writes to the system log as well:

```
NSLog("i=%ld, x=%f, status=%@", 123, 34.56, "OK")
```

---

Note also that on OS X, `syslog()` is just a wrapper to the
["Apple System Logger facility"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/asl.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/asl). You can call
the `asl_XXX` functions directly, you only have to `#include <asl.h>`
in the bridging header file. As above, `asl_log()` is not
imported to Swift and you have to call `asl_vlog()` instead.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! I have found `vsyslog` but I had not idea how work with `CVaListPointer`.

Comment: @ValentinShergin: You are welcome. – Re your edit: You were right about the typo. But `message : String` was intentional and works because a Swift string is converted automatically when passed to a C function taking a `const char *` parameter, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27063569/string-value-to-unsafepointeruint8-function-parameter-behavior.

Comment: Yes, I realised that I was wrong after I send the edit, but there is no way to cancel edit on SO. Sorry for the mess. :(
Swift is awesome, you are awesome too.