# How do I replace the current Swift script process with a different one

Tags: swift, macos, terminal, scripting

When using Ruby, the following will terminate the current ruby script and replace the process with an instance of ssh:

`exec "ssh host -p 1234 -v"`

Is this possible to do in Swift?

Comment: There used to be a `system` API in Swift, but it is deprecated in favor of the `posix_spawn` APIs and `NSTask`.  I'd start with those.

Comment: @JAL: Those are slightly different, posix_spawn create a new process. The execX functions replace the existing process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`execv`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/execv.3.html) and related functions from the BSD library
can be called from Swift (with the exception of those with a variable 
argument list). The only "challenge" is to create a

```
UnsafePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?>
```

that can be passed as the argument list. A simple example:

```
import Foundation

let args = ["ls", "-l", "/Library"]

// Array of UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>
let cargs = args.map { strdup($0) } + [nil]

execv("/bin/ls", cargs)

fatalError("exec failed")
```

Here it is used that you can pass a Swift string to the 
C function `strdup()` which expects a `const char *`, and the
compiler creates a temporary UTF-8 representation (see
[String value to UnsafePointer<UInt8> function parameter behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27063569/string-value-to-unsafepointeruint8-function-parameter-behavior)).

Comment: So this works, other than I also had to add `cargs.append(nil)` just before calling `execv`. Thanks!