# Swift to C bridging: String to UnsafePointer<Int8>? is not automatically bridged?

Tags: c, swift, vulkan, bridging-header

While trying to interface with a C library (Vulkan) I am faced with the following error while trying to assign a Swift(4.2) native String to C String

```
error: cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'UnsafePointer<Int8>?'
```

I'm doing a simple assignment

```swift
var appInfo = VkApplicationInfo()
appInfo.pApplicationName = "Hello world"
```

Wasn't Swift supposed to handle these through its automatic bridging?

Comment: Automatic bridging can't help here, because it doesn't solve the memory management problem. You're passing a Swift string to C code that doesn't play by Swift's ARC rules. I think you need to use Unmanaged<T> in this case, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Alexander: `Unmanaged<T>` won't help here, that is only used with *classes* `T`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The automatic creation of a C string representation from a Swift `String` is only done when calling a function taking a `UnsafePointer<Int8>` argument (compare [String value to UnsafePointer<UInt8> function parameter behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27063569/string-value-to-unsafepointeruint8-function-parameter-behavior?noredirect=1&lq=1)), and the C string is only valid for the duration of the function call.

If the C string is only need for a limited lifetime then you can do

```
let str = "Hello world"
str.withCString { cStringPtr in
    var appInfo = VkApplicationInfo()
    appInfo.pApplicationName = cStringPtr

    // ...
}
```

For a longer lifetime you can duplicate the string:

```
let str = "Hello world"
let cStringPtr = strdup(str)! // Error checking omitted for brevity
var appInfo = VkApplicationInfo()
appInfo.pApplicationName = UnsafePointer(cStringPtr)
```

and release the memory if it is no longer needed:

```
free(cStringPtr)
```