# Mutable C String in Swift

Tags: swift, string, language-interoperability, unsafemutablepointer

I’m writing Swift code that interfaces with a C library. The library exposes an incomplete struct, which I’m wrapping in a Swift class. The initializer function for this struct takes a `char*` argument, or `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>` in Swift. The library doesn’t provide a way to assign a different pointer later.

I’m trying to figure out how to get an `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>` to a Swift string, with two main requirements. First, the string should be mutable without changing the pointer. Second, the pointer (and String)’s lifetime should be as long as the wrapper object's.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: Some feedback on the answer would be appreciated :) Let me know if you need more information!

Answer (score 4):

A pointer to a C string representation of a Swift string is obtained with

```
s.withCString { cStringPtr in
    callCFunction(cStringPtr)
}
```

but there are two problems: First, the storage pointed to by the pointer is not mutable. If the C function is declared as taking a `char *` but does not actually mutate the string (i.e. if it *should* have been declared as taking a `const char *` argument) then you can make the pointer mutable with

```
s.withCString { cStringPtr in
    let mutableCStringPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: cStringPtr)
    callCFunction(mutableCStringPtr)
}
```

But this pointer still refers to the same (immutable) storage, i.e. this causes undefined behavior if the C function mutates the C string.

The second problem with this approach is that the pointer is only valid for the execution of the closure. You cannot take the pointer and save it for later usage. This would be undefined behavior:

```
let mutablePointer = s.withCString { cStringPtr in
    UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: cStringPtr)
}

// Use `mutablePointer` later.
```

For a longer lifetime (i.e. the lifetime of the wrapper instance) one must allocate memory and copy the C string. This can for example be done with `strdup()`:

```
class Wrapper {
    var cStringPtr: UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>

    init(s: String) {
        guard let cStringPtr = strdup(s) else {
            // Handle "no memory" error ...
        }
        self.cStringPtr = cStringPtr
    }

    deinit {
        free(cStringPtr)
    }
}
```

(If you wonder why a Swift string can be passed to `strdup()` directly, see [String value to UnsafePointer<UInt8> function parameter behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27063569/string-value-to-unsafepointeruint8-function-parameter-behavior).)