# How to a meaningfull error message with SQLITE and swift

Tags: swift, sqlite

How do I get a meaningfull error message like "table 'table_that_does_not_exist' doesn't exists" for my following sample ?

```
    var sql = "select * from table_that_does_not_exist";
    var statement:COpaquePointer = nil

    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &statement, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
        println("Failed to prepare statement");
        var result=sqlite3_errmsg(db);
        println(result);
        exit(1);
    }else{
```

My prinltn in this sample reports : "0x0000000102ee3380", which doesn't say something to me nor to google. (ok, when I don't know its not surprising :-) , but google)

**UPDATE SOLUTION**
As CL. explained, this is C-pointer returned.
So I have to get the message like :

```
let errmsg=String.fromCString(sqlite3_errmsg(db));
```

Thanks a lot to CL.

Comment: actually it is not my intention to solve my missing table issue (which is only a sample) :-). I just want an error message so I could figure out what is the problem. This is only a sample. In future I will have other problems (not like this simple sample of a missing table), and then I would like to get an error message from the db.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Working with C strings in Swift, or: How to convert UnsafePointer<CChar> to CString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24418955/working-with-c-strings-in-swift-or-how-to-convert-unsafepointercchar-to-cstr)

Comment: Thanks, but I see no relation to the mentoined question. This is something totally different. Or can you help me pointing out, how I can get the errormessage from the mentoined question ?

Comment: `sqlite3_errmsg()` returns a C string.

Comment: Thanks a lot CL ! Now I got it. I updated the question with the solution.