# How to use appendFormat to format a string in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsmutablestring

I want to append a string to a NSMutableString using appendFormat, inserting white spaces to get a minimum length for my string.

In objective-c, i just used

```
[text.mutableString appendFormat:@"%-12s", "MyString"];
```

and I would get

```
"MyString    "
```

But in Swift, I tried

```
text.mutableString.appendFormat("%-12s", "MyString")
```

and I get everything, but not "MyString    ". It appears some random characters that I do not know where it came from.

Is there anyone who knows why that happens, and what I should do?

Thank you guys!

Comment: I can reproduce this in a Playground, the random characters change every time the code is run. Using `str += String(format:"%-12s", "Hello")`, and variants.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use String's method [stringByPaddingToLength()](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByPaddingToLength:withString:startingAtIndex:) as follow:

```
let anyString = "MyString"
let padedString = anyString.stringByPaddingToLength(12, withString: " ", startingAtIndex: 0)  // "MyString    "
```

Comment: This works well too, added an example using this method to my answer. It's much more obvious as well (where as the cstring conversion will need a comment to explain what's going on).

Comment: In Swift 5, method name has been changed to `padding(toLength:withPad:startingAt:)`.

Answer (score 5):

Through Ken's explanation that a Swift String object is *not* equivalent to the Objective-C C-style string (a null-terminated array of `char`) I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24103828/1217087) which shows how to convert a Swift String object into a Cstring, which the `%-12s` formatting works correctly on.

You can use your existing formatting string as follows:

```
text.mutableString.appendFormat("%-12s", ("MyString" as NSString).UTF8String)
```

Some examples:

```
var str = "Test"
str += String(format:"%-12s", "Hello")
// "Test–yç       " (Test, a dash, 11 random characters)

var str2 = "Test"
str2 += String(format:"%-12@", "Hello")
// "TestHello" (no padding)

var str3 = "Test"
str3 += String(format:"%-12s", ("Hello" as NSString).UTF8String)
// "TestHello       " ('Hello' string is padded out to 12 chars)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
text.mutableString.appendFormat("%-12@", "MyString")
```

In Swift, `"MyString"` is a `String` *object*. The `%s` format specifier causes `appendFormat()` to interpret its argument as a C-style string (a buffer of `char` terminated by a null `char`).

In Objective-C, `"MyString"` is just such a C-style string. You would have to prefix it with an `@` to get an `NSString` object (`@"MyString"`).

Comment: What do you mean "nothing happened"? The statement does *something*. Adam points out that Cocoa doesn't seem to respect the field width in the format specifier when using `%@`, which is disappointing. That seems like a Cocoa bug.

Comment: Thank you sir! Just one addition: Swift's `String` is not an object, afaik, it's a struct.

Answer (score 1):

```
    let space: Character = " "
    text = "MyString" + String(count: 12, repeatedValue: space)
```

Comment: This will simply append 12 spaces to the end of the string, rather than padding the string _up to_ a minimum of 12 characters.

Comment: yeah the string MyString could change to another string with a different length, that's why I need something simple that could do the complex work for me