# swift : use of %s in String(format: ...)

Tags: swift, string, format

I would like to format a string with another string like this:

```
var str = "Hello, playground"
print (String(format: "greetings %s", str))
```

This leads to this beautiful result:

> greetings 哰૧

I tried with %@ and it works but, as I'm getting format string from
another programming language, I would like, if possible to use the %s tag.
Is there a way to ?

Comment: The `"%s"` format specifier specifies a _C_ string — a null-terminated sequence of bytes. It will also not properly handle non-ASCII/UTF-8 encodings. Can you not search for "%s" in the format string you get and replace it with "%@"?

Comment: `%s` expects a C-string, not a Swift string.

Comment: Why not just use `"greetings \(str)"`?

Comment: If you want CString: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103590/how-do-you-convert-a-string-to-a-cstring-in-the-swift-language (there is a Swift 3 answer)

Comment: I would avoid the format constructor in String as much as possible. The %s escape isn't made for  Objective-C nor Swift strings, it's for C String only. Avoid the %s in the localized text at any cost too...

Comment: Interesting that the creators of Swift decided %s should NOT work with String. Not sure what benefit that provides? And could it not be overloaded somehow?

Answer (score 38):

#### Solution 1: changing the format

If the format is from a reliable external source, you can convert it to replace occurences of `%s` with `%@`:

So, instead of:

```
String(format: "greetings %s", str)
```

You do:

```
String(format: "greetings %s".replacingOccurrences(of: "%s", with: "%@"), str)
```

---

#### Solution 2: changing the string

[If the format is complex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52332747/what-are-the-supported-swift-string-format-specifiers), a simple replacement won't work. For instance:

- when using a specifier with a numeric character sequence: `%1$s`
- when using the '%' character followed by an 's': `%%s`
- when using a width modifier: `%-10s`

In similar cases, we need to stick to a C string.

So instead of:

```
String(format: "greetings %s", str)
```

You do:

```
str.withCString {
    String(format: "greetings %s", $0)
}
```

Comment: Solution 2 doesn't work with non-ASCII/UTF-8 strings