# What are the supported Swift String format specifiers?

Tags: swift, string, string-formatting

In Swift, I can format a String with format specifiers:

```
// This will return "0.120"
String(format: "%.03f", 0.12)
```

But the official documentation is not giving any information or link regarding the supported format specifiers or how to build a template similar to `"%.03f"`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/3126742-init

It only says:

> Returns a String object initialized by using a given format string as a template into which the remaining argument values are substituted.

Comment: There are links to the supported formats in documentation for the various `NSString init(format:...)` initializers.

Comment: I submitted a bug report to Apple to update the `String` documentation to include the same links in the `NSString` documentation. Others should do the same. It's a shame Apple has made it hard to submit documentation feedback.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

The format specifiers for `String` formatting in Swift are the same as those in Objective-C `NSString` format, itself identical to those for `CFString` format and are buried deep in the archives of Apple Documentation (same content for both pages, both originally from year 2002 or older):

- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFStrings/formatSpecifiers.html
- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

But this documentation page itself is incomplete, for instance the *flags*, the *precision* specifiers and the *width* specifiers aren't mentioned. Actually, it claims to follow [IEEE printf specifications (Issue 6, 2004 Edition)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html), itself aligned with the ISO C standard. So those specifiers should be identical to what we have with C `printf`, with the addition of the `%@` specifier for Objective-C objects, and the addition of the poorly documented `%D`, `%U`, `%O` specifiers and `q` length modifier.

---

### Specifiers

> Each conversion specification is introduced by the '%' character or by the character sequence "%n$".

`n` is the index of the parameter, like in:

```
String(format: "%2$@ %1$@", "world", "Hello")
```

### Format Specifiers

> %@    Objective-C object, printed as the string returned by descriptionWithLocale: if available, or description otherwise.

Actually, you may also use some Swift types, but they must be defined inside the standard library in order to conform to the CVarArg protocol, and I believe they need to support bridging to Objective-C objects: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/object_runtime/classes_bridged_to_swift_standard_library_value_types.

```
String(format: "%@", ["Hello", "world"])
```

> %%    '%' character.

```
String(format: "100%% %@", true.description)
```

> %d, %i    Signed 32-bit integer (int).

```
String(format: "from %d to %d", Int32.min, Int32.max)
```

> %u, %U, %D    Unsigned 32-bit integer (unsigned int).

```
String(format: "from %u to %u", UInt32.min, UInt32.max)
```

> %x    Unsigned 32-bit integer (unsigned int), printed in hexadecimal using the digits 0–9 and lowercase a–f.

```
String(format: "from %x to %x", UInt32.min, UInt32.max)
```

> %X    Unsigned 32-bit integer (unsigned int), printed in hexadecimal using the digits 0–9 and uppercase A–F.

```
String(format: "from %X to %X", UInt32.min, UInt32.max)
```

> %o, %O    Unsigned 32-bit integer (unsigned int), printed in octal.

```
String(format: "from %o to %o", UInt32.min, UInt32.max)
```

> %f    64-bit floating-point number (double), printed in decimal notation. Produces "inf", "infinity", or "nan".

```
String(format: "from %f to %f", Double.leastNonzeroMagnitude, Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
```

> %F    64-bit floating-point number (double), printed in decimal notation. Produces "INF", "INFINITY", or "NAN".

```
String(format: "from %F to %F", Double.leastNonzeroMagnitude, Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
```

> %e    64-bit floating-point number (double), printed in scientific notation using a lowercase e to introduce the exponent.

```
String(format: "from %e to %e", Double.leastNonzeroMagnitude, Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
```

> %E    64-bit floating-point number (double), printed in scientific notation using an uppercase E to introduce the exponent.

```
String(format: "from %E to %E", Double.leastNonzeroMagnitude, Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
```

> %g    64-bit floating-point number (double), printed in the style of %e if the exponent is less than –4 or greater than or equal to the precision, in the style of %f otherwise.

```
String(format: "from %g to %g", Double.leastNonzeroMagnitude, Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
```

> %G    64-bit floating-point number (double), printed in the style of %E if the exponent is less than –4 or greater than or equal to the precision, in the style of %f otherwise.

```
String(format: "from %G to %G", Double.leastNonzeroMagnitude, Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
```

> %c    8-bit unsigned character (unsigned char).

```
String(format: "from %c to %c", "a".utf8.first!, "z".utf8.first!)
```

> %C    16-bit UTF-16 code unit (unichar).

```
String(format: "from %C to %C", "爱".utf16.first!, "终".utf16.first!)
```

> %s    Null-terminated array of 8-bit unsigned characters.

```
"Hello world".withCString {
    String(format: "%s", $0)
}
```

> %S    Null-terminated array of 16-bit UTF-16 code units.

```
"Hello world".withCString(encodedAs: UTF16.self) {
    String(format: "%S", $0)
}
```

> %p    Void pointer (void *), printed in hexadecimal with the digits 0–9 and lowercase a–f, with a leading 0x.

```
var hello = "world"
withUnsafePointer(to: &hello) {
    String(format: "%p", $0)
}
```

> %n    The argument shall be a pointer to an integer into which is written the number of bytes written to the output so far by this call to one of the fprintf() functions.

***The `n` format specifier seems unsupported in Swift 4+***

> %a    64-bit floating-point number (double), printed in scientific notation with a leading 0x and one hexadecimal digit before the decimal point using a lowercase p to introduce the exponent.

```
String(format: "from %a to %a", Double.leastNonzeroMagnitude, Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
```

> %A    64-bit floating-point number (double), printed in scientific notation with a leading 0X and one hexadecimal digit before the decimal point using a uppercase P to introduce the exponent.

```
String(format: "from %A to %A", Double.leastNonzeroMagnitude, Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
```

### Flags

> '    The integer portion of the result of a
>   decimal conversion ( %i, %d, %u, %f, %F, %g, or %G ) shall be
>   formatted with thousands' grouping characters. For other conversions
>   the behavior is undefined. The non-monetary grouping character is
>   used.

***The `'` flag seems unsupported in Swift 4+***

> -    The result of the conversion shall be left-justified within the field. The conversion is right-justified if
>   this flag is not specified.

```
String(format: "from %-12f to %-12d.", Double.leastNonzeroMagnitude, Int32.max)
```

> +    The result of a signed conversion shall always begin with a sign ( '+' or '-' ). The conversion shall begin
>   with a sign only when a negative value is converted if this flag is
>   not specified.

```
String(format: "from %+f to %+d", Double.leastNonzeroMagnitude, Int32.max)
```

> <space>    If the first character of a signed
>   conversion is not a sign or if a signed conversion results in no
>   characters, a <space> shall be prefixed to the result. This means
>   that if the <space> and '+' flags both appear, the <space> flag
>   shall be ignored.

```
String(format: "from % d to % d.", Int32.min, Int32.max)
```

> #    Specifies that the value is to be converted to an alternative form. For o conversion, it increases the precision
>   (if necessary) to force the first digit of the result to be zero. For
>   x or X conversion specifiers, a non-zero result shall have 0x (or 0X)
>   prefixed to it. For a, A, e, E, f, F, g , and G conversion specifiers,
>   the result shall always contain a radix character, even if no digits
>   follow the radix character. Without this flag, a radix character
>   appears in the result of these conversions only if a digit follows it.
>   For g and G conversion specifiers, trailing zeros shall not be removed
>   from the result as they normally are. For other conversion specifiers,
>   the behavior is undefined.

```
String(format: "from %#a to %#x.", Double.leastNonzeroMagnitude, UInt32.max)
```

> 0    For d, i, o, u, x, X, a, A, e, E, f, F, g,
>   and G conversion specifiers, leading zeros (following any indication
>   of sign or base) are used to pad to the field width; no space padding
>   is performed. If the '0' and '-' flags both appear, the '0' flag is
>   ignored. For d, i, o, u, x, and X conversion specifiers, if a
>   precision is specified, the '0' flag is ignored. If the '0' and '"
>   flags both appear, the grouping characters are inserted before zero
>   padding. For other conversions, the behavior is undefined.

```
String(format: "from %012f to %012d.", Double.leastNonzeroMagnitude, Int32.max)
```

### Width modifiers

> If the converted value has fewer bytes than the field width, it shall be padded with spaces by default on the left; it shall be padded on the right if the left-adjustment flag ( '-' ) is given to the field width. The field width takes the form of an asterisk ( '*' ) or a decimal integer.

```
String(format: "from %12f to %*d.", Double.leastNonzeroMagnitude, 12, Int32.max)
```

### Precision modifiers

> An optional precision that gives the minimum number of digits to appear for the d, i, o, u, x, and X conversion specifiers; the number of digits to appear after the radix character for the a, A, e, E, f, and F conversion specifiers; the maximum number of significant digits for the g and G conversion specifiers; or the maximum number of bytes to be printed from a string in the s and S conversion specifiers. The precision takes the form of a period ( '.' ) followed either by an asterisk ( '*' ) or an optional decimal digit string, where a null digit string is treated as zero. If a precision appears with any other conversion specifier, the behavior is undefined.

```
String(format: "from %.12f to %.*d.", Double.leastNonzeroMagnitude, 12, Int32.max)
```

### Length modifiers

> h    Length modifier specifying that a following
>   d, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a short or unsigned
>   short argument.

```
String(format: "from %hd to %hu", CShort.min, CUnsignedShort.max)
```

> hh    Length modifier specifying that a following
>   d, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a signed char or
>   unsigned char argument.

```
String(format: "from %hhd to %hhu", CChar.min, CUnsignedChar.max)
```

> l    Length modifier specifying that a following
>   d, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a long or unsigned
>   long argument.

```
String(format: "from %ld to %lu", CLong.min, CUnsignedLong.max)
```

> ll, q    Length modifiers specifying that a
>   following d, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a long long
>   or unsigned long long argument.

```
String(format: "from %lld to %llu", CLongLong.min, CUnsignedLongLong.max)
```

> L    Length modifier specifying that a following
>   a, A, e, E, f, F, g, or G conversion specifier applies to a long
>   double argument.

***I wasn't able to pass a CLongDouble argument to `format` in Swift 4+***

> z    Length modifier specifying that a following
>   d, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a size_t.

```
String(format: "from %zd to %zu", size_t.min, size_t.max)
```

> t    Length modifier specifying that a following
>   d, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a ptrdiff_t.

```
String(format: "from %td to %tu", ptrdiff_t.min, ptrdiff_t.max)
```

> j    Length modifier specifying that a following
>   d, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a intmax_t or
>   uintmax_t argument.

```
String(format: "from %jd to %ju", intmax_t.min, uintmax_t.max)
```

Answer (score 8):

Probably supports all of below, which summarizes the format specifiers supported by `NSString`
([source](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)).

The format specifiers supported by the `NSString` formatting methods and CFString formatting functions follow the [IEEE printf specification](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html); the specifiers are summarized in below (**Table 1**). Note that you can also use the "`n$`" positional specifiers such as `%1$@ %2$s`. For more details, see the [IEEE printf specification](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html). You can also use these format specifiers with the `NSLog` function.

### Format Specifiers <sup>(Table 1)</sup>

| Specifier | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `%@` | Objective-C object, printed as the string returned by `descriptionWithLocale:` if available, or `description` otherwise. Also works with `CFTypeRef` objects, returning the result of the `CFCopyDescription` function. |
| `%%` | `'%'` character. |
| `%d`, `%D` | Signed 32-bit integer (`int`). |
| `%u`, `%U` | Unsigned 32-bit integer (`unsigned int`). |
| `%x` | Unsigned 32-bit integer (`unsigned int`), printed in hexadecimal using the digits 0--9 and lowercase a--f. |
| `%X` | Unsigned 32-bit integer (`unsigned int`), printed in hexadecimal using the digits 0--9 and uppercase A--F. |
| `%o`, `%O` | Unsigned 32-bit integer (`unsigned int`), printed in octal. |
| `%f` | 64-bit floating-point number (`double`). |
| `%e` | 64-bit floating-point number (`double`), printed in scientific notation using a lowercase e to introduce the exponent. |
| `%E` | 64-bit floating-point number (`double`), printed in scientific notation using an uppercase E to introduce the exponent. |
| `%g` | 64-bit floating-point number (`double`), printed in the style of `%e` if the exponent is less than --4 or greater than or equal to the precision, in the style of `%f` otherwise. |
| `%G` | 64-bit floating-point number (`double`), printed in the style of `%E` if the exponent is less than --4 or greater than or equal to the precision, in the style of `%f` otherwise. |
| `%c` | 8-bit unsigned character (`unsigned char`). |
| `%C` | 16-bit UTF-16 code unit (`unichar`). |
| `%s` | Null-terminated array of 8-bit unsigned characters. Because the `%s` specifier causes the characters to be interpreted in the system default encoding, the results can be variable, especially with right-to-left languages. For example, with RTL, `%s` inserts direction markers when the characters are not strongly directional. For this reason, it's best to avoid `%s` and specify encodings explicitly. |
| `%S` | Null-terminated array of 16-bit UTF-16 code units. |
| `%p` | Void pointer (`void *`), printed in hexadecimal with the digits 0--9 and lowercase a--f, with a leading `0x`. |
| `%a` | 64-bit floating-point number (`double`), printed in scientific notation with a leading `0x` and one hexadecimal digit before the decimal point using a lowercase `p` to introduce the exponent. |
| `%A` | 64-bit floating-point number (`double`), printed in scientific notation with a leading `0X` and one hexadecimal digit before the decimal point using a uppercase `P` to introduce the exponent. |
| `%F` | 64-bit floating-point number (`double`), printed in decimal notation. |

### Length modifiers <sup>(Table 2)</sup>

| Length modifier | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `h` | Length modifier specifying that a following `d`, `o`, `u`, `x`, or `X` conversion specifier applies to a `short` or `unsigned short` argument. |
| `hh` | Length modifier specifying that a following `d`, `o`, `u`, `x`, or `X` conversion specifier applies to a `signed char` or `unsigned char` argument. |
| `l` | Length modifier specifying that a following `d`, `o`, `u`, `x`, or `X` conversion specifier applies to a `long` or `unsigned long` argument. |
| `ll`, `q` | Length modifiers specifying that a following `d`, `o`, `u`, `x`, or `X` conversion specifier applies to a `long long` or `unsigned long long`argument. |
| `L` | Length modifier specifying that a following `a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `f`, `F`, `g`, or `G` conversion specifier applies to a `long double` argument. |
| `z` | Length modifier specifying that a following `d`, `o`, `u`, `x`, or `X` conversion specifier applies to a `size_t`. |
| `t` | Length modifier specifying that a following `d`, `o`, `u`, `x`, or `X` conversion specifier applies to a `ptrdiff_t`. |
| `j` | Length modifier specifying that a following `d`, `o`, `u`, `x`, or `X` conversion specifier applies to a `intmax_t` or `uintmax_t` argument. |

> Length modifier example:
>
> ```m
> #include <limits.h>
>
> // ...
>
> NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Signed %hhd, Unsigned %hhu", CHAR_MIN, UCHAR_MAX];
> ```
>
> Or in Swift:
>
> ```
> let text = String(format: "Signed %hhd, Unsigned %hhu", CChar.min, CUnsignedChar.max)
> ```

### Platform Dependencies

OS X uses several data types---`NSInteger`, `NSUInteger`,`CGFloat`, and `CFIndex`---to provide a consistent means of representing values in 32- and 64-bit environments. In a 32-bit environment, `NSInteger` and `NSUInteger` are defined as `int` and `unsigned int`, respectively. In 64-bit environments, `NSInteger`and `NSUInteger` are defined as `long` and `unsigned long`, respectively. To avoid the need to use different printf-style type specifiers depending on the platform, you can use the specifiers shown in Table 3. Note that in some cases you may have to cast the value.

**Table 3**  Format specifiers for data types

| Type | Format specifier | Considerations |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `NSInteger` | `%ld` or `%lx` | Cast the value to `long`. |
| `NSUInteger` | `%lu` or `%lx` | Cast the value to `unsigned long`. |
| `CGFloat` | `%f` or `%g` | `%f` works for floats and doubles when formatting; but note the technique described below for scanning. |
| `CFIndex` | `%ld` or `%lx` | The same as `NSInteger`. |
| pointer | `%p` or `%zx` | `%p` adds `0x` to the beginning of the output. If you don't want that, use `%zx` and no typecast. |

The following example illustrates the use of `%ld` to format an `NSInteger` and the use of a cast.

```
NSInteger i = 42;
printf("%ld\n", (long)i);
```

In addition to the considerations mentioned in Table 3, there is one extra case with scanning:
you must distinguish the types for `float` and `double`.
You should use `%f` for float, `%lf` for double.
If you need to use `scanf` (or a variant thereof) with `CGFloat`, switch to `double` instead,
and copy the `double` to `CGFloat`.

```
CGFloat imageWidth;
double tmp;
sscanf (str, "%lf", &tmp);
imageWidth = tmp;
```

It is important to remember that `%lf` does not represent `CGFloat` correctly on either 32- or 64-bit platforms.
This is unlike `%ld`, which works for `long` in all cases.

Comment: Since you mentioned NSLog, let's note that it supports extra specifiers, like `%{BOOL}d` for... YES or NO. You can find the table of those extra specifiers with `man 3 os_log` on macOS.

Answer (score -2):

**Swift 5**

```
    let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
    let dateFormat = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "jm", 
                                    options: 0, locale: Locale.current)!
    timeFormatter.dateFormat  = dateFormat
```