# Why doesn't my conversion of Double to String work, in Swift?

Tags: swift

What am I doing wrong?
I want to convert a Swift Double into a String.

```
let aaa: Double = 94.1
let bbb = String(format: "%d", aaa )
print("bbb:", bbb )
```

OUTPUT...

> bbb: 1717986918

Comment: Because `%d` is for "integer" values, try `%f`. Interestingly, your code produces `"0"` for me.

Comment: You might consider using `NumberFormatter` instead, for [example](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/formatting-numbers-in-swift/) and [example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter)

Comment: FYI - you may wish to see [What are the supported Swift String format specifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52332747/what-are-the-supported-swift-string-format-specifiers) for more details about format specifiers.

Answer (score 5):

The format specifier `%d` is for integer values. For floating point you need to use `%f`. Note that this will default to 6 decimal places.

It would be much simpler to use string interpolation instead of old style `printf` style formatting.

```
let bbb = "\(aaa)"
```

You could also make use of `NumberFormatter` or the newer `formatted` on types like `Double`.

Answer (score 1):

For floating-point numbers like Double, you need to use the `%f` format specifier:

```
let aaa: Double = 94.1
let bbb = String(format: "%.1f", aaa)
print("bbb:", bbb)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use `NumberFormatter`:

```swift
let double: Double = 94.1
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
if let string = formatter.string(for: double) {
    print(string) // 94.1
}

// or:
print(double.formatted()) // 94.1
```

Comment: No need for the `NSNumber`. Just change `formatter.string(from: number)` to `formatter.string(for: double)`.

Answer (score 0):

To correctly convert a **Double** into a **String** representation with one decimal place, you should use the %0.1f format specifier. you can changed the format specifier according to your need.

Here is the corrected code:

```
let aaa: Double = 94.1
let bbb = String(format: "%.1f", aaa)
print("bbb:", bbb)
```

now it should display "94.1" as expected.